# How do I find the Parents name of each place belongs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http

```
public class ZipListViewModel 
{
    /// <summary>HIERARCHY_CODE</summary>
    public string HIERARCHY_CODE{ get; set;}

    /// <summary>prent_zipcode/summary>
    public string Zip_1{ get; set;}

    /// <summary> parent_name /summary>
    public string ZipName_1 { get; set;}

    /// <summary>place zipcode /summary>
    public string Zip_2 { get; set;}

    /// <summary>LOCATION</summary>
    public string LOCATION { get; set;}
}


var db = new Entities(); 
var source = from a in db.ZIP
select new ViewModels.ZipListViewModel
{
    ID = a.ID,
    HIERARCHY_CODE = a.HIERARCHY_CODE,
    Zip_1 = a.ZIP_1,
    Zip_2 = a.ZIP_2,
    LOCATION = a.LOCATION
};
```

`Zip_1` is `Zip_2` parent's zipCode. the `HIERARCHY_CODE` is `{ 0, 1 , 2 }` ，for every city's hierarchy

i went to this show `ZipListViewModel` like this

```
  ID = a.ID,
  HIERARCHY_CODE = a.HIERARCHY_CODE,
  Zip_1 = a.ZIP_1,
  *ZipName_1 =a.ZipName_1*,
  Zip_2 = a.ZIP_2,
  LOCATION =a.LOCATION
```

how can i do this?
I explain more clearly.
the dataBase Data  like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 200px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                HIERARCHY_CODE</td>
            <td>
                Zip_1</td>
            <td>
                Zip_2</td>
            <td>
                Location</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                0</td>
            <td>
                480</td>
            <td>
                480</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;Arizona</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                1</td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;480&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                85048&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                Phoenix</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can i show **Phoenix** belongs to **Arizona** in this `VeiwModel`, 
like `Zip1_name='Arizona'`

Comment: it's not clear what do you want to show in `ZipName_1` property. Is it correspond with `HIERARCHY_CODE` somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to add `ParentLocation` `string` property to your `ZipListViewModel` and then store in that field location `string` that you need.

If you don't have relations in your BD model than you can do it like this:

```
var db = new Entities();
var source = db.ZIP.Select(x => new ViewModels.ZipListViewModel
    {
        ID = x.ID,
        HIERARCHY_CODE = x.HIERARCHY_CODE,
        Zip_1 = x.ZIP_1,
        Zip_2 = x.ZIP_2,
        LOCATION = x.LOCATION,
        ParentLocation = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Zip_1) ? db.ZIP.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Zip_2 == x.Zip_1).LOCATION : String.Empty
    });
```

This is Extension Methods syntax.